# why isn't python accessible from within a bash script?

Tags: python, macos, bash

i have the following script

```
cd desktop/rttex
for i in $(find . -iname '*.rttex');
do
Python unpack.py $i $i.png
done
```

this should go through each file in the folder and if it matches the .rttex extension then it should run python unpack.py (unpack.py takes file names as the infile.rttex and outfile.png arguments)

however when it gets to the running of the python script it errors saying python command not found. it works perfectly when python infile.rttex outfile.png is run directly from the terminal.

is there something i need to change to get it working from within a bash script?

Comment: Is it because the command should be `python` not `Python`?

Comment: Possibly, although `Python` and `python` are identical when searching for executables when using the default HFS+ settings.

Comment: Could you post the output of `echo $PATH`, run directly from the terminal and run from a script?

Comment: How are you running this script? Is it possible that python is on the `PATH` for your normal interactive shell sessions, but you're trying to, say, run it as a launch agent, which isn't using a normal interactive shell session?

Comment: if it helps its within an automator workflow. path from within automator is /usr/bin:bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin and path from terminal is     /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Can you do `which python` and `which Python`  in the terminal, and let us know what you get?

Comment: jamess-imac:rttex jamesgpollock$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
jamess-imac:rttex jamesgpollock$ which Python
/usr/local/bin/Python
jamess-imac:rttex jamesgpollock$

Comment: You need to use `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of `python` or you need to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` of automator.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to run

```
which Python
```

to find out where your binary is located, and then replace the Python call in your script with the full path.

Background is, that not all paths are checked when executing scripts.